# Questions about how to adjust p.value by FDR

Tags: r, false-discovery-rate

I am adjusting a group of p-value by FDR in R. For example

```
 p.value= c(0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.5,0.8,0.9)
```

I see some papers used the following function.

```
p.adjust(p.value,method = "fdr",n=length(p.value))
```

But I think FDR is used to control the numbers of false positive. Thus, the adjustment object is the p value less than 0.05? There is no need to adjust the negative (p>0.05)?

May I adjust the p.value like the following function?

```
p.value_n=p.value[p.value<0.05]
p.adjust(p.value_n,method = "fdr",n=length(p.value_n))
```

I am not sure my thought is right or wrong?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may not adjust the p-value like that. Your thought is wrong. By dropping the non-significant tests, you are pretending you never performed them at all. The FDR correction is less aggressive, leading to more false discoveries.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that FDR is used to control the numbers of false positive.

But it changes also p-values that are greater than 0.05. However, after applying FDR adjustment, p-value never drops, it can remain the same as before adjustment or rise. Therefore p-values greater than 0.05 will remain greater than 0.05.

This may suggest that one can safely drop p-values greater than 0.05 in his/her calculation, but it is not true. This is because number of conducted tests (number of obtained p-values) is crucial for FDR (and any other p-value correction method).

Imagine you have only one significant p-value, say p=0.01, in your study. In first scenario it is one of three obtained p-values. In second it is one of thousand. In first case you have 3 tests with 5% probability of type-I error each, in second you have 1000 of them. Your conclusions about "corrected" significance should be quite different, right?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot for your reply!
I still have some questions about multiple hypothesis test. 
**Situation 1:** We have 1000 p-values, all of them are less than 0.0 5. We may say there are 50 false positive (1000*0.05) in these p-values. 
**Situation 2:** We have 1000 p-values, all of them are greater than 0.05. Can we still say there are 50 false positive in the p-values. Apparently, it is unreasonable. Because there are not positive in these p-values. 
Multiple hypothesis test is used to control false positive. So the premise is that we must have positive. Together, I think the adjustment object is the p values those are less than 0.05, not all the p-values including p-values >0.05. I am not sure my though is wrong or right? Any insight would be greatly appreciated!